# How to check used amplifiers?

Tags: amplifier

When buying used amplifiers: Is there a way to check if they are still working, are in good condition and will not die at the next possibility? Checking used speakers is easy, but I have no idea how to do that for amplifiers.
Thus: Are there general guidelines for that?

Comment: I'm not sure how this wouldn't be production oriented.  Assuming it is dealing with sound reinforcement amplifiers, then it is 100% production oriented and firmly on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just plug it in to some speakers and see if it produces clean sound?  I don't really see why it would be any harder or easier than for speakers.  You test both out by trying them.  You could additionally check if it runs hot or shows any signs of damage on the transformers potentially, if you are actually able to take it apart to inspect it.